# Android using qt library

Tags: android, qt

it's necessary to use Qt library in my project, so what you please advice me how better to use sources written in pure Qt? I don't need a UI, just some code, is it necessary to use Necessitas or just include into project build QtEverywhere sources & that's it? 
just .so with using of code written in Qt without any UI dependencies.
Thanks.

Comment: Why do you absolutely need to use Qt? It's an anti practice on android.

Comment: imagine company has some codebase(some library) written using Qt & what it's necessary to do? Write the same? If anyway for performance will be used native code, why don't use already written Qt sources? It's not about UI, it's about engine classes...

Comment: I'm not sure why this got down voted.  It's a valid question, even if it is not something others would recommend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I was doing the project, I would use [Necessitas](https://necessitas.kde.org/).  It should only bring the parts you need over.  If you don't use / link to the GUI, it shouldn't need to install it.

The big advantage I see to Necessitas are that it is actively maintained, all of the work of configuring / adjusting things to run on Android has already been done, and it comes with a full tool chain, not just sources that you must build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I want to use Qt as just UTILS lib without any UI stuff: threads, timers... If I'll use Necessitas, will it necessary to install Ministro? I just want 1 .so as output which I'll use in my .apk, without any additional Ministro installations, also I've a commercial license for Qt.

Answer (score 1):

It strongly depends on what you need from Qt. Consider that compiling some parts of Qt for Bionic needs changes to the code. You could take the Qt libraries compiled by Necessitas but you'd still need a QCoreApplication instance for many qt classes to work, like QTimer for instance. Many Qt classes only work when a Qt event loop is running. I tried [this solution](https://sites.google.com/site/lukeshq/engineering-articles/embedded-cross-platform-development) for small codes.

Using necessitas for the entire project might be simpler, but it depends on the application you want to write. I ported applications which were completely written in C++ with a QML interface: in this particular situation the porting is simple and the interface can be hardware accelerated. Unfortunately, in this situation if you want to access to the Android classes, you need to implement JNI bindings.

Comment: I want use Qt lib, there is no any UI & I want it as 1 single .so as output, whitout Ministro. Want build it using Android NDK. Is that possible?

Comment: Possible? Yes. You need ministro only if you don't want to bundle the Qt libraries in your apk. Otherwise Ministro is useless. If you want to have a single shared library as a result, you need to link all the modules into you shared library. You have to use the Android NDK, but in that case, either you use the necessitas libs or you need to do some fixes to the Qt framework to compile against Bionic. Still, the event loop is needed.

Comment: It's ok, I think in my Android app, in java it will be necessary to call a native method & create instance of QCoreApplication & then use all Qt API without limitations..Am I right? I'm new in Qt..Where it's possible take compiled Qt for android & how it's possible to integrate this into android NDK project/source, what write into the Android.mk file?

Comment: The link I reported have some notes which answers all your questions and I see you're not even bothering accepting answers to your past questions.